# Django url contains unwanted characters

Tags: django

My url in Django contains whitespaces, which is not exactly what I want in this case. I have searched for a solution ofcourse. I'd need some kind of urlencoding for the url. I have also seen the `slugify`, but it did not seem to work.

```
<a href="{% url 'detail' title=example.label %}">view more</a>
```

Now this redirects to the other url and sets the example.label in the url. Now that could be any string, so it contains whitespaces and characters.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^$', search,
            name='search'),
    url(r'^example/(?P<title>.+)/$', detail,
            name='detail'),
]
```

How would I apply some kind of encoding so the url could look like `example/an%20example%title/` instead of `example/An Example Title` like it does now? All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Django has a standard model method `get_absolute_url()`. I would define it for your Example model, so that you can use

```
<a href="{{ example.get_absolute_url }}">view more</a>
```

in the template.

On the model, you can do all the replacements and complicated URL path constructions, using Python

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    title = self.title.replace(' ', '%20').lower()
    return reverse('detail', kwargs={'title': title})
```

---

**Edit:** Or you could create a simple filter to return the correct path

```
@register.filter(name='detailurl')
def detailurl(value):
    value = value.replace(' ', '%20').lower()
    return reverse('detail', kwargs={'title': value})
```

In your app directory, create a sub directory `templatetags` and place the filter into `example_tags.py`:

```
exampleapp/templatetags/__init__.py
exampleapp/templatetags/example_tags.py
```

To use the filter, you need to load the namespace (the filename) first

```
{% load example_tags %}
<a href="{{ example.label|detailurl }}">view more</a>
```

[More about custom filters here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/)

Comment: The thing is: I do not use any model at this moment. It is a bunch of API calls. The main page lists multiple items, with a button next to it to 'view more'. Any way to do it without putting this function on a model?

Comment: Then I would suggest to make a simple filter. I added it to my answer.

Comment: Thanks, will defenitely try that one